# Which metric to use for imbalanced classification problem?

Tags: random-forest, metrics, multilabel-classification, imbalanced-data, boosting

I am working on a classification problem with very imbalanced classes. I have 3 classes in my dataset : class 0,1 and 2. Class 0 is 11% of the training set, class 1 is 13% and class 2 is 75%.

I used and random forest classifier and got 76% accuracy. But I discovered 93% of this accuracy comes from class 2 (majority class). Here is the [Crosstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkw0U.png) I got.

**The results I would like to have :**

- fewer false negatives for class 0 and 1  OR/AND  fewer false positives for class 0 and 1

**What I found on the internet to solve the problem and what I've tried :**

- using *class_weight='balanced'* or customized *class_weight* ( 1/11% for class 0, 1/13% for class 1, 1/75% for class 2), but it doesn't change anything (the accuracy and crosstable are still the same). Do you have an interpretation/explenation of this ?
- as I know accuracy is not the best metric in this context, I used other metrics : *precision_macro*, *precision_weighted*, *f1_macro* and *f1_weighted*, and I implemented the area under the curve of precision vs recall for each class and use the average as a metric.

Here's my code (feedback welcome) :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

def pr_auc_score(y_true, y_pred):
    y=label_binarize(y_true, classes=[0, 1, 2])
    return average_precision_score(y[:,:],y_pred[:,:])

pr_auc = make_scorer(pr_auc_score, greater_is_better=True,needs_proba=True)
```

and here's a plot of the [precision vs recall curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yfhn.png).

Alas, for all these metrics, the crosstab remains the same... they seem to have no effect

- I also tuned the parameters of Boosting algorithms ( XGBoost and AdaBoost) (with accuracy as metric) and again the results are not improved.. I don't understand because boosting algorithms are supposed to handle imbalanced data
- Finally, I used another model (BalancedRandomForestClassifier) and the metric I used is accuracy. The results are good as we can see in this [crosstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4BXx.png). I am happy to have such results but I notice that, when I change the metric for this model, there is again no change in the results...

So I'm really interested in knowing why using class_weight, changing the metric or using boosting algorithms, don't lead to better results...

Comment: Did you try Xgboost using array of weights? I have used xgboost for imbalanced binary class classification and setting scale_pos_weight improved the performance of model. As u have a multi class classification u can not use scale_pos_weight unless you use one vs rest approach, but instead you can use array of weights and that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have figured out, you have encountered the "accuracy paradox";

Say you have a classifier which has an accuracy of 98%, it would be amazing, right? It *might* be, but if your data consists of 98% class 0 and 2% class 1, you obtain a 98% accuracy by assigning *all* values to class 0, which indeed is a bad classifier.

So, what should we do? We need a measure which is invariant to the distribution of the data - entering ROC-curves.

- ROC-curves are invariant to the distribution of the data, thus are a great tool to visualize classification-performances for a classifier whether or not it is imbalanced. But, they only work for a two-class problem (you can extend it to multiclass by creating a one-vs-rest or one-vs-one ROC-curve).
- F-score might a bit more "tricky" to use than the ROC-AUC since it's a trade off between [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) and you need to set the beta-variable (which is often a "1" thus the F1 score).

You write: "*fewer false negatives for class 0 and 1 OR/AND fewer false positives for class 0 and 1*". Remember, that all algorithms work by either minimizing something or maximizing something - often we minimize a loss function of some sort. For a random forest, lets say we want to minimize the following function L:

```
L = (w0+w1+w2)/n
```

where `wi` is the number of class `i` being classified as not class `i` i.e if `w0=13` we have missclassified 13 samples from class 0, and `n` the total number of samples.

It is clear that when class 0 consists of most of the data then an easy way to get a small `L` is to classify most of the samples as `0`. Now, we can overcome this by adding a weight instead to each class e.g

```
L = (b0*w0+b1*w1+b2*x2)/n
```

as an example say `b0=1, b1=5, b2=10`. Now you can see, we cannot just assign most of the data to `c0` without being punished by the weights i.e we are way more conservative by assigning samples to class 0, since assigning a class 1 to class 0 gives us 5 times as much loss now as before! This is exactly how the `weight` in (most) of the classifiers work - they assign a penalty/weight to each class (often proportional to it's ratio i.e if class 0 consists of 80% and class 1 consists of 20% of the data then `b0=1` and `b1=4`) but you can often specify the weight your self; if you find that the classifier still generates to many false negatives of a class then increase the penalty for that class.

Unfortunately "there is no such thing as a free lunch" i.e it's a problem, data and usage specific choice, of what metric to use.

On a side note - "random forest" might actually be bad by design when you don't have much data due to how the splits are calculated (let me know, if you want to know why - it's rather easy to see when using e.g Gini as splitting). Since you have only provided us with the ratio for each class and not the numbers, I cannot tell.